# This page isn’t working, Currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 on Laravel

Tags: laravel, hosting, cpanel

Before Laravel, I have been using the MVC Web Framework and success to host in cPanel server.

Now, I decide to upgrade my Framework. So I find Laravel because it also included MVC patterns and easy to learn for me. Seeing some tutorials, I decided to host a simple project of Laravel on a subdomain of my main domain sites.

What I did:

**On server**:

1. I create a subdomain and set the document root to `/public_html/subdomain.maindomain.com/public`.
2. Inside the public_html folder, I created a folder and renamed as just like to subdomain name.

**On My Computer**

```
composer global require laravel/installer
laravel new website
php artisan serve
```

Now, I get the Laravel homepage on browser link `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.
Then, I added bootstrap.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

Then, I see the login and register link on the Laravel homepage.

Now, seeing https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment documentation of Laravel:

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
```

Now, I uploaded the zip file (all files inside the website folder) and extracted it to server document root `/public_html/subdomain_name/`. In the subdomain_name folder, I have all the files that were in my website folder on my computer.

I don't change anything on the `index.php` file of the public folder, remain on default condition.

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php;
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then, I check my URL but I faced `This page isn’t working, subdomain.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: why don't you check the error log to see why it was causing a 500 error

Comment: how can i check the error log? I don't know how to check because I am a fresh beginner at Laravel

Comment: the webserver's logs

Comment: one more thing, where you have subdomain here $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../subdomain_name/bootstrap/app.php'; is not suppose to be subdomain but your laravel package name, the name on the folder you uploaded

Comment: @lagbox Yes, I find error log file in my public folder, the error is in the above in the question, see there I updated. But what to debug on its, It is default file of laravel.

Comment: would seem you don't have a high enough version of PHP on that server ... check the installation documentation for the version of Laravel you are using it will tell you the requirements

Comment: Isn't it support larval on my server? I updated server information with png image. check that

Comment: well 'nullable types' was added in 7.1 and that is what the error is saying it doesn't support, so that is not running 7.3.x for your site

Comment: In https://laravel.com/docs/8.x documentation, it is written  'PHP >= 7.3' then what I understood that my server PHP s 7.3.x. So, it should support, AM I WRONG? And should I need to change the server?

Comment: the error is because it does not support a feature from PHP 7.1, so it would seem it is less than 7.1

Comment: Should I follow https://laravel.com/docs/5.5 documentation, it is written 'PHP >= 7.0.0'

Comment: in your control panel find out how to adjust the version of PHP that is being used ... check the help section or poke around until you can figure it out

Comment: I update the error log, after changing PHP version to 7.1. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

First of all upload the laravel to your domain root folder and not public_html and extract, then move the content of the public folder of your laravel to `/public_html/subdomain.maindomain.com/public` then edit the content of the index.php `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; equire_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` to this `require __DIR__.'/../../../laravelpackagename/vendor/autoload.php' and $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../laravelpackagename/bootstrap/app.php';`  
Not tested but I believe this should work

Comment: My domain root is set to /public_html. So do I need to move the Laravel file to path that you saying?

Comment: am not talking about your subdomain root, I mean your domain root, there is no way your domain root will be public_html

Comment: it should look similar to /Home/laravelpackage

Comment: I fixed it, @lagbox help me to figure out my error. How did I fix it? see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How did I solve this error:

I re-create the Laravel new project just like the above command and put that file to my server path to `/public_html/laravel/`. Therefore, I didn't change anything on the `index.php` file on the public folder, remain to the default condition. By doing this still error remains same (HTTP ERROR 500).

Then, I look at the error_log file at `/public_html/laravel/public/`, and see an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in public_html\laravel\vendor\ramsey\uuid\src\functions.php line on 34.`

In cPanel MultiPHP Managers, I select my sites and set the PHP Version to the same version it has before [PHP 7.3 (ea-php73)]. Then, BOOM!! It worked. I see the homepage of my laravel project in the URL.

In brief, selecting the same PHP Version in cPanel MultiPHP Managers, help me to solve this error.

Comment: Your solution helped me find a solution to mine